# How to use stored procedure in EF by using uow pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have an interface by the name `IunitOfWork` in my `DataLayer` :

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    int SaveChanges();

    IList<TEntity> SQLQueries<TEntity>( string _sql ) where TEntity : class;

}
```

and my `Context`:

```
public class Context : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
   public DbSet<Slider> MySlider { get; set; }
    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {
            return base.Set<TEntity>();
         }


     public IList<TEntity> SQLQueries<TEntity>( string _sql ) where TEntity : class
     {
        return base.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(_sql).ToList();
        // Is it good to use 'ToList()' here or not??
     }
 }
```

and in my `Service` I have:

```
public  interface ISlider
{

    IList<DomainModel.Slider> SliderGetAll();
  }
```

and :

```
public class Slider:ISlider
{
       IUnitOfWork _uow;
    IDbSet<DomainModel.Slider> _slider;
    IList<DomainModel.Slider> _slider2;



    public Slider( IUnitOfWork uow )
    {
        _uow=uow;
        _slider = _uow.Set<DomainModel.Slider>();

    }
    public IList<DomainModel.Slider> SliderGetAll()
    {

        var slide=_uow.SQLQueries<DomainModel.Slider>("SliderGetAll");
        return slide;
    }
  }
```

It's working in this way, I want to know its a good way which I use `Stored Procedure`?

NOTE: I used Structure Map for DI.

Comment: Can someone move that over to codereview?